# how can i write text into a textbox using WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, mechanize, www-mechanize

i have been trying to write text into a textbox using WWW::Mechanize,

i am not able to figure out a way to enter text into a textbox, does WWW::Mechanize support such feature,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you need is here (its a pretty simple thing to want to do, so it of course supports it):

[http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech->field(*$name,*$value,*$number*)](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#%24mech-%3Efield%28_%24name,_%24value,_%24number_%29)

Don't forget to select the form first, prior to trying to set the fields within it